# Adding transparent (through text and navbar) text to navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transparency

I'm working on building a website with bootstrap, and I have a navbar fixed to the top of the window.  I'm trying to make the abbreviated logo (BLM) on the left of the bar transparent through the letters and the navbar (so that whatever is on the page can be seen through the letters).

Anyone know what css (or html) needs to be added to do this?

Below is my navbar code:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BLM</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#"class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">The Team <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">PersonA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PersonB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PersonC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PersonD</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The part I'm talking about making transparent through to the page is

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BLM</a>
```

I can use CSS to make the navbar-brand transparent, but then it's just black because the navbar is black (and I don't want the navbar to be transparent).

[image]
In this example, I want to be able to see the red wall through the BLM letters

Thanks for any help/thoughts!!

Comment: You can't do that with CSS...even with transparent text it will always show the background of the parent elements (or their parents) through the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no CSS feature (yet) that does what you want it to do while being cross-browser compatible. However, the solution to your problem is easy.

**Replace your logo with a .png with transparent letters and a semi-transparent background that matches the rest of the navbar**. Shuffle around your divs so that your logo and the rest of the navbar are separate elements, and you're done!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom! I'm not sure how to split the navbar or any of that, so definitely not an "easy" solution. But I'll look all that up and give it a try.  The issue is that I was trying to have a css-blur effect in my navbar, which I won't be able to do if I split it and put the logo. But, should still achieve most of my desired effect.

Comment: I looked at your code, and you actually don't need to split anything at all; you already have a separate element for your logo (.navbar-brand). In your css, set `display:inline-block` for that element, set the background-color to none, and add your background-image. You can still have your CSS blur if you want to :)

Comment: Tom, thank you so much!! should I insert the image in CSS or html?  Could you explain how? I tried inserting a png image in-between the <a> </a> using html, and it doesn't appear in the navbar, but half-in and half-below

Answer (score -1):

Try `opacity` and a value of a decimal.

```
.navbar-brand {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I've done this, but as I explained above, this just makes the text more transparent, showing the black navbar below. I need to see through the navbar to the page.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, maybe if you explain or illustrate what you're actually trying to achieve with a fiddle or an illustration I can help you achieve what you actually need to do.

Comment: Haha, I didn't down vote your answer bud! Must have been someone else! I can make a JSfiddle though, I'll post one in a second

Comment: @Acoustic77 What you are trying to do is **not** possible. If any parent element (or parent of a parent) has a background---that is what will show through the text.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's definitely possible, I just need to edit the css of the navbar or navbar-brand class or both.

Comment: It is not possible unless you turn the black background itself into a background image and mask out the letters.

Comment: @SeanLinehan I saw you solved this (your puppy picture), That's almost exactly what I'm trying to do (navbar opacity and all). Can you help here?

Comment: Have you tried setting the opacity for the entire navbar itself? and then for the text portion as well?

Comment: Looks like it's possible, tried a few of these things though and can't get it: https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/   http://css-tricks.com/animated-knockout-letters/